# SQL Server Aggregate Summary row of other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write SQL to generate a rowset like the below? Where one row is an aggregation of the other rows.

```
    Column1 Column 2
    Value1   12
    Value2   11
    Value3   6   
    Value4   17
    total    46
```

Comment: can provide more detail .

Comment: Use `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`

Comment: Lol those don't add up to 36.

Comment: Arithmetic wasn't covered in my CS curriculum :/

Comment: @KaushikThanki I left the example simple so as to make it generic. I'm open to suggestions as to how to rename the question though, if that isn't clear for someone searching for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Group by` with [**`ROLLUP`**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522495(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT*
         FROM   (VALUES ('Value1',12),
                        ('Value2',11),
                        ('Value3',6 ),
                        ('Value4',17)) tc (Column1, Column2))
SELECT column1= case when grouping(column1) = 1 then  'total' else column1 END,
       column2=Sum(column2)
FROM   cte
GROUP  BY rollup( column1 )
```

**Result :**

```
column1 column2
------- -------
Value1  12
Value2  11
Value3  6
Value4  17
total   46
```

Comment: Small note, rather than using `ISNULL` to determine if it's the total column, you may want to use `CASE WHEN GROUPING(column1) = 1 ...` to eliminate any weird issues they might have with legitimate `NULL` values in their real data.